# making function like strcmp() in C

Tags: c

am making function like strcmp() witch finds a name in 2d array of names 
if the name is there it simply returns 0 , else returns -1 , my problem is when i use this code it returns 0 just when i type the first element of arrayOfnames.

```
int my_strcmp(char arrayOfNames[5][20], char nameToFind[20])
{
    int i,j;
    for (j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
      for (i = 0; arrayOfNames[j][i] &&nameToFind[i]; ++i)
      {
          if (arrayOfNames[j][i] == nameToFind[i])
             continue;
          else
             break;
      }
      if (arrayOfNames[j][i] == nameToFind[i])
         return 0;
      else  //Set the 6th bit in both, then compare
         return -1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Then use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).  I'm not sure you are right in giving fixed dimensions to your arrays or string.

Comment: `return -1;` too early. To be located outside of the loop

Comment: yup, the return statement is to early thanks BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the array you pass are the dimensions 5,20 then you have a mistake in the first for loop:

```
for (j=0;j<=5;j++)
```

Where you go out of bounds

```
for (j=0;j<5;j++)
```

is the correct loop

However this comment *//Set the 6th bit in both, then compare* indicates that you have larger dimensions than specified.

The better way to form your function would be to specify the dimensions with additional parameters and pass an additional array for storing results.

Comment: its just the return statement return -1 i shouldn't  put it inside the loop, and for the "=" when i remove it , it doesn't pass to the last element